# Is it possible to customise Krita’s FFMPEG render?

Tags: video

As Windows 10's native media players *still* don't support the YUV444p pixel format, which seems to be FFMPEG's default format, is it possible for a Krita user to easily (or relatively easily) reconfigure Krita’s FFMPEG command line to specify, say, YUV420p?

While downloading the VLC Media Player is, of course, an option, as is ‘simply’ collecting Krita’s PNG file render output and running FFMPEG against them manually, life would be a lot easier if Krita’s render workflow was seamless at this point.

While I don’t mind tinkering around at the command prompt, it’s not ideal for people who’ve grown up in a GUI environment. So. Any helpful suggestions or workarounds, anybody?

Comment: You do not want your master file be anything other than 444 Otherwise you just throw pixels out. So its very very problematic if you set your default to something less than this. Anyway add a codec to your windows codec repository for the yuv444

Comment: We throw pixels away all the time: it's the price we pay if we want to get played.


Can you suggest a source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [code](https://github.com/KDE/krita/blob/cbf812208bd951ec0f1c309add844257604723b3/plugins/extensions/animationrenderer/video_export_options_dialog.cpp#L322), you need to set the profile in Video Export Options to `high` and Krita will force the pixel format to yuv420p. There also appears to be a `Custom Options` field where you could fill `-pix_fmt yuv420p` but if the profile is incompatible (like `high422`), ffmpeg will bail out.